# DeltaTime issue at program start

Tags: android, game-physics

i have a problem with deltaTime ive been using. My Code is the following:

```
public class Time {
    public static float deltaTime = 0;                      
    public static long frameCount = 0;                      
    public static float fixedTime = 0;                     
    public static float fixedDeltaTime = 0.1f;      
    public static float maxDeltaTime = 0.25f;
```

}

And now in my MainThread.java in my run() function:

```
 while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                float newTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0f;
                Time.deltaTime = frameTime = newTime - currentTime;

                if(frameTime > Time.maxDeltaTime)
                        frameTime = Time.maxDeltaTime;

                currentTime = newTime;

                accumulator += frameTime;

                while(accumulator > Time.fixedDeltaTime)
                { 
                        this.gamePanel.update();   // where the player and my enemy gets updated                         
                        accumulator -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
                }

                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
                //Perform all non-physics-related updates here


                ++Time.frameCount;

                framesSkipped = 0;  // resetting the frames skipped

                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                    if (sleepTime > 0) {
                            // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                            try {
                                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);    
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }

                    while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                            // we need to catch up
                            this.gamePanel.update(); // update without rendering
                            sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  // add frame period to check if in next frame
                            framesSkipped++;
                    }

                    if (framesSkipped > 0) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Skipped:" + framesSkipped);
                    }
                            // for statistics
                            framesSkippedPerStatCycle += framesSkipped;
                            // calling the routine to store the gathered statistics
                            storeStats();
                }
            } finally {
                // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
                // an inconsistent state
                    if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
            } //end finally

    }
```

}

in the gamePanel.update() ive got the update calls for the player and my enemy.
Now my Problem is, that at the start of my game the deltaTime is extremly high und thus my movement is very fast, because i have the following in my enemy class in the update method:

```
                   x += vX * Time.deltaTime; // velocity * deltaTime
                   y -= vY * Time.deltaTime;
                   //Log.d(TAG, "Time:"+Time.deltaTime+" x: "+x+" y: "+y);
                   vY -= gravity;
```

Am i doing it right, or is something wrong with my structure?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `currentTime` before the start of the loop. You don't show how it's being initialized, but my guess it starts at 0, so on the first loop iteration, `deltaTime` is being set to the current time as returned by `System.nanoTime()`.

P.S. Is there some reason you are using `System.nanoTime()` in one place and `System.currentTimeMillis()` in another? Also, consider sticking to computing everything in milliseconds (or nanoseconds) with `long` values and eliminating the floating point calculations.

Comment: Jeah u are right. currentTime is initally set to 0. What do you suggest setting it on? System.nanoTime() , too? Wouldnt be that bad if the movement would be 0 at the start. Thanks so far

Comment: @ the P.S. No im using the millisconds to calculate the avgFps / currentFPS. While i was testing the deltaTime i didnt want to affect the fpsCount. But i guess for my purposes millseconds would have been enough!

Comment: @puelo - I'd initialize it to System.nanoTime(). Movement would be zero for the first iteration because the game is just starting. This would happen for only one frame. (My guess is that you have the same problem with `beginTime`, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Ive just noticed that i messed the copying up. beginTime should be fine.